# AngularJS access scope from outside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show the count of items repeated in my ng-repeat but how to I access this from outside the ng-repeat?

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/SYqb8h9k81SlVY3Yzhgx

HTML:

```
<h3>Number of locations is: {{location.length}}</h3>

<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="location in locations" on-finish-render>

    {{location.siteName}}

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="listOfLocations in location.locationsList track by $index">
            {{listOfLocations}}
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('locationAccordionCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.locations = [
    {
      "siteName":"First Location",
      "locationsList":['First Location 1', 'First Location 2', 'First Location 3']
    },
    {
      "siteName":"Second Location",
      "locationsList":['Second Location 1', 'Second Location 2', 'Second Location 3']
    },
    {
      "siteName":"Third Location",
      "locationsList":['Third Location 1', 'Third Location 2', 'Third Location 3']
    }
  ];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h3>` tag must be in the scope of the `locationAccordionCtrl`. So, put it inside the `<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">` tag. Also, you have to say `{{locations.length}}` instead of `{{location.length}}` (missing the "s")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that it is outside of `ng-repeat`, but rather that it is outside your controller. The following should work:

```
<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">
<h3>Number of locations is: {{locations.length}}</h3>
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the bind inside the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">
  <h3>Number of locations is: {{locations.length}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="location in locations" on-finish-render>

    {{location.siteName}}

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="listOfLocations in location.locationsList track by $index">
            {{listOfLocations}}
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="locationAccordionCtrl">

<h3>Number of locations is: {{locations.length}}</h3>

<div ng-repeat="location in locations" on-finish-render>

{{location.siteName}} ({{location.locationsList.length}})

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="listOfLocations in location.locationsList track by $index">
        {{listOfLocations}}
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```